# Using AD with tortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

In windows, is it possible for TortoiseGit to use the credentials of the currently logged user, or via LDAP, rather than the user having to enter in a user name and password and this getting stored?

For us, using git-credential-wincred option for the credentials_helper setting isn't feasible. The user environment is very restricted and locked down, and administered by a third party. A change to an AD account password it can result in a wait of days (they have a 4 day response in the SLA) before the credentials are removed and the user can get back to using TortoiseGit.

So storing the passwords is not a realistic option. For now Credential_helper is set to none, forcing the users to enter the username & password on every push. Not the ideal situation, but better than a 4 day wait.

*[edit]*

A few more details about our environment. It's an HVD, based on a master image. The master image is maintained by another company, and each time the users log on, their session is created from the master image. The users cannot install anything on it. They cannot make changes to the setup or settings. They cannot access the internet with it. There's no command line (OS, Git bash or anything else). There is only restricted access to a handful of internal servers.

The master image has TortoiseGit and Git, and we have GitLab on one of the server that the HVD can access.

Comment: Maybe using ssh keys could be an option, cf. https://help.cloudforge.com/hc/en-us/articles/215243143-Configure-TortoiseGIT-client-to-work-with-SSH-keys-on-Windows

Comment: Some Git server instances might also allow to generate a token which is used as a password.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provide more information about the server side.

Comment: If passwords being changed is the concern you could use gitlab access tokens instead - manually generating them and then entering them at the wincred prompt. Looks like gitlab had no token generating api yet, but when they did you could write your own credentials helper to generate and store a token for them